# Qt Serial Communication not sending all data

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am writing a Qt application for serial communication with a Qorvo MDEK-1001. All built-in serial commands I've had to use work fine except for one: aurs n k, where n and k are integers corresponding to the desired rate of data transmission (e.g. "aurs 1 1\r"). Write function is:

```
void MainWindow::serialWrite(const QByteArray &command)
{
    if(mdek->isOpen())
    {
        mdek->write(command);
        qDebug() << "Command: " << command;
        //mdek->flush();
    }
}
```

If I send the command "aurs 1 1\r". It doesn't actually get sent to the device until I send another command for some reason. So if I subsequently send the "quit" command to the device, the returned data from the device is: "aurs 1quit", which registers as an unknown command. Any assistance getting this command to send properly is appreciated.
I've tried a bunch of stuff (setting bytes to write as second parameter in write(), using QDataStream, appending individual hex bytes onto QByteArray and writing that), but nothing has worked. This is the first time I've had to use Qt's serial communication software so I've probably missed something obvious.

On Linux Manjaro (same thing happens on Windows 8.1)
Connection settings: 8 data bits, Baud: 115200, No Flow Control, No Parity, One Stop Bit

Comment: Are you sure that you aren’t blocking the main loop?  The bytes to write will be queued and will get written out when control passes back to the main loop

Comment: And are you sure the command terminator is `\r` and not `\n`? From the return value I would guess that `\r` is not the correct one - otherwise the return value would be different.